# Formating the tittle of a graph that has varabiles and latex

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

i was trying to make a graph tittle change depending on the users input  using the following piece of code   `plt.title(f"{a}$x^2+{b}x+{c}$")`

i would like it to display the title of the graph in the most simple form for example when a=1 b=0 c=-1

i want it to display x-1 as the title

but instead it is displaying 1x+0x+-1 as the tittle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Simple python code:**

```
a = 1
b = 0
c = -1


def format_title(a, b, c):
    title = ''
    if a == 1:
        title += 'x^2'
    else:
        title += f'{a}x^2'
    if b != 0:
        if b > 0:
            title += '+'
        title += f'{b}x'
    if c != 0:
        if c > 0:
            title += '+'
        title += f'{c}'
    return title


 print(format_title(a, b, c))
```

**Output:**

```
x^2-1
```

Answer (score 0):

A more complicated, but generalisable option would be:

```py
def ft(*coefs, exponent="x", cdp=0):
    title = ""
    cstring = f"{{:.{cdp}f}}"  # number of decimal places to format the coefficents
    nc = len(coefs) - 1
    for i in range(nc, -1, -1):
        if coefs[nc - i] != 0:
            # get the sign
            sign = "+" if coefs[nc - i] > 0 and i < nc else ("-" if i == nc and coefs[nc - i] == -1 else "")
            
            # get the coefficient
            c = cstring.format(coefs[nc - i]) if abs(coefs[nc - i]) != 1 or i < nc else ""
            
            # get the exponent
            exp = f"{exponent}^{i}" if i > 1 else (exponent if i == 1 else "")
            part = f"{sign}{c}{exp}"
            title += f"{part}"
    
    return f"${title}$"
```

This can take in any number of coefficients (so not just quadratics) and also output the coefficients with to any number of decimals places (it defaults to just output with no decimal places, i.e., as integers). For you case you still have:

```
print(ft(1, 0, -1))
$x^2-1$
```

but you could also do, e.g.,

```
print(ft(-4.765, 0, 2.383, -0.351, cdp=2))
$-4.76x^3+2.38x-0.35$
```